# Linux crash dumps not working

Tags: linux

I'm using Gentoo and I've carefully followed and triple-checked the instructions on the following page but the crash kernel will not boot so I don't get anything in /proc/vmcore:

http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kernel_Crash_Dumps

Comment: I'd add more info to clarify your question if possible. There's not much here to go on.

Comment: What happens when you try to boot it?

Comment: I agree not much to go on. @david, when the system crashes it just locks up.  From what I understand, it's supposed to automatically reboot into the crash kernel at that point.

Comment: How would you debug this if you found yourself in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the crashkernel itself crashes when I have the Mini DisplayPort connected.  I've filed a bug:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62671